# MS-Word not allowing users to save a SharePoint document which has a field with multiple taxonomy terms

Tags: sharepoint, metadata, office-2013

I tried creating an out of the box document library and added one taxonomy field.  After I created a document and added a number of terms (about 50).  If I try to edit the document in word it gives me an error because of the Document Information Panel when trying to save.

I think there is a limit with the number of characters in a field in the out of the box Document Information Panel.  I am using SharePoint 2013 and Office 2013.  Any ideas how to get around this issue?